# Get last insert id return null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have db table images with primary key `ID` and auto increment. Am adding new images with `ajax > controller > model`.

My model for create has method `create`

```
  public function create($data = array())
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);

        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

  public function getLastInserted() {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
  }
```

And in controller i create test metod to check what is last id inserted:

```
public function lastID()
{
   var_dump($this->photo->getLastInserted());
}



// int(0)
```

But record is succeffull inserted in database. What can be problem ?

Comment: because you already retrieve last insert id in `create` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create function return last insert id. To see your last insert id just use this code in controller function

```
public function lastID()
 {
  var_dump($this->photo->create('table_name',$data));
 }
```

photo model function

```
function create($tableName, $data)
 {
    $this->db->insert($tableName, $post);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
 }
```

Comment: Return error `You must use the "set" method to update an entry.`

Comment: In this process you can insert and return  id successfully. @zend

Comment: So how can i return that `ID` in ajax `success`. Can u show me example ?

Comment: in controller function `echo $id=$this->photo->create('table_name',$data);` this variable return id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106147/discussion-between-rakib-roni-and-zend).

Answer (score 2):

From the official docs: **mysqli::$insert_id - Returns the auto generated id used in the LAST query**

Make sure you are not doing any other queries **AFTER** your `create()` method.

I would suggest to place a last inserted ID into class variable, to avoid problems like these in the future:

```
private $lastInsertId = null;

public function create($data = array())
{
    $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);
    $this->lastInsertId = $this->db->insert_id();

    return $this->lastInsertId;
}

public function getLastInserted() {
    return $this->lastInsertId;
}
```

Comment: Again i get NULL after success created record!

Comment: Make sure you are not doing any other queries after create(), if you do then store insert_id from create() into other var which isn't updated after.

Comment: Hmm that is problem bcs i have some ajax request for selecting records from db. Like fetch user posts

Answer (score 0):

`lastInsertid` only works when you use it on your db connection variable like

```
dbconnection->lastInsertId()
```